# i am getting compilation error, when i build maven

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

[ERROR] /D:/EclipseWorkSpace/Hibernate_Practice/src/main/java/com/dao/UserDaoImpl.java:[6,21] cannot access org.hibernate.Session
bad class file: C:\Users\Sreenivasulu.P.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.1.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar(org/hibernate/Session.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

52 means JDK 1.8 and 55 means JDK11, further it means that you are trying to compile your project with mixed JDK11 and JDK8.
Three places where you need to set your JDK with the sam value:

1. Eclipse Java Build Path ( Installed JREs )
2. Eclipse Java Compiler
3. PC Terminal ( JAVA_HOME )

Also Hibernate 6 does not work well with Spring 5 due to the package name changes ( in 6 it's jakarta, in 5 it is javax ), so it would be wise to downgrade to Hibernate 5.

After these changes delete the content of your .m2 folder, right click on your project > Maven > Update.
Then you can run `mvn clean install` from your terminal.